# Changing Themes Not Applying

Tags: unity, themes, unity-tweak-tool

When trying to select a non-default theme in the Unity Tweak Tool, the row is selected, but the theme does not change.

I have tried:

- Rebooting
- Reinstalling the theme I am trying to use (Arc)
- Reinstalling the Unity Tweak Tool
- Using dconf-editor to reload the XSettings daemon

Screenshots:

[Default theme (Adwaita)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQr0o.png)

[Changing the theme causes the row to glow orange, but the system appearance does not change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Ai5.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and resolved it by the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool
```

Then delete the contents of `var/cache/apt/archives/`

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install unity-tweak-tool from Software Center